# MAT01 Matched NPN Transistors - Substrate bias voltage

Tags: transistor-array

I am working on a logarithmic amplifier based around the MAT01GHZ matched pair.

In the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/mat01.pdf), a note states:
The collector to base and collector to emitter leakage currents can be reduced by a factor of 2 to 10 times by connecting the substrate (package) to a potential that is lower than either collector voltage.

Since I am operating from a ± 5V supply, is it advisable to directly connect the substrate (via a case connection) to -5VDC, or should I supply a smaller magnitude negative voltage, for example by connecting the substrate to the emitters? One collector sits at a virtual ground point and the other is a few hundred mV above ground.

The MAT01 does not have integral protection diodes, unlike other transistor arrays, such as the MAT02, MAT12, CA3046. For the latter, the substrate is usually connected to the most negative point of the circuit, but I'm worried I might cause damage and mismatching, as I'm unaware of the structural relationship between the transistors and the substrate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substrate will be a fine node to inject noise / trash / VDDspikes into your circuit.

Model this IC, for this purpose, as 100 pF capacitors from substrate node to each collector node. The collectors are in a "tub" or a well, surrounding the base region which surrounds the emitter region. The collectors are easily 20X by 20X larger (400X the area) of the emitter.

I suggest you use an RC lowpass filter to bias the substrate node to the most negative. Use 1Kohm and 1nanoFarad, **if** your noise injection modeling (using the 100 pF I suggested) shows the noise currents (from VDD spikes of a switching_regulator) will upset your signal chain.

The datasheet may show collector_to_substrate values greatly different from the 100pF value I suggested. Notice the datasheet value is at a HIGH voltage, such as 20 volts. Thus 100pF is more conservative.

Use the RC lowpass only if you need to. First task is to prepare an error budget, with awareness of your signal bandwidth and of the risetime of spikes on your VDD.

=====================================

Examining the MAT01 datasheet, there is no data given on C_substrate_collector, though the case is tied to the substrate. I'd assume 100pF in any simulation.
The datasheet shows 8pF collector-to-collector, thus the substrate_collector is at least double that, or 16pF.

The collectors are tied to the case, which is 9 mm across.

Thus the case is a fine metal object to gather electric field flux, and inject those displacement currents into your circuit.

The case is approximately a square centimeter of area.
Assume a switching power supply 1cm away, with 10 volts in 10nanoseconds slewrate. What is the current injected into the case/substrate/collectors?

Using parallel_plate model (and ignoring fringing), the capacitance thru the air is

C = 9pF/meter * area/distance = 9pF * 0.01 = 0.09pF

The injected current is (using Q = C*V, differentiated to be I = C * dV/dT with constant C)

I = 0.09pF * 10 volts/10nanoseconds

I = (0.09 * 0.001 * 1nF) * 1v/1nS

and cancelling the 1nF by the 1nS

I = 0.09 * 0.001 = 90 microAmps of spikes / trash / noise injected into your collectors.

Does your error budget allow that?

Comment: Hi analogsystemsrf,

Admittedly, I haven't put much thought into bandwidth considerations. The logging amplifier is intended for sub-Hz, DC signals. I'm using a well-filtered linear supply and the circuit will be shielded in a metal box (as far as noise coupling goes).
I think biasing through a LPF is a good idea. From your comments, I assume that the -5V to case will not cause any physical problems (I'm worried about breakdown from the substrate.
I hope that makes sense. I'm not an EE by education, but I rely on a scientific background to understand these concepts.

Comment: Datasheet shows leakage data is taken with 45+ volts collector. No information is given on how the  transistors are constructed. Thus 5 (five) volts is quite conservative. Regarding noise, keep all logic signals well away. No MCU is quiet, because the constant internal clocking causes the GND and VDD rails to be constantly bouncing around, by +- 0.5 volts with 1 or 2 nanosecond edges. Thus even "Sleep" or "Mode" signals are not to be trusted near your very low-current analog circuits.

Comment: Consider shielding your DC power wires, where those wires enter your metal box. Wires are antennas for RF/AM/FM/LCD displays and any black-brick wall-warts within 10 feet.

Comment: The project is a high dynamic range measurement instrument. I've tried to take into account proper shielding and leakage prevention within and outside the device. I'm working on a write-up/lessons learned article, which I will follow up with here.

Comment: @ Nikola D   Looking forward to your "lessons learned" writeup.